# GoogleMaps API: Follow and Center my watchpostion without reloading the map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Since several months I am looking for a solution. I found really interesting things - like Google Maps Library Utilities but nothing that could help me.

I want to get my location on google maps by using watchPosition and following (center) my location without reload the map.

Everytime I center the location on watchPosition it reload the map. Maybe there is a way with overlays but Unfortunately, I lack the knowledge.

The best way would be using Geomarker from Google Maps Library Utilities. But the same here. I can't center it.

Maybe anyone could help me with a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var map;
            var GeoMarker;
            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

                GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
                GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
                    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                    map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
                });

                navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
                    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    map.setCenter(geolocpoint);
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
                    alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
                });
                GeoMarker.setMap(map);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            if(!navigator.geolocation) {
                alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reload the map.

Use the `setPosition`-method of the marker to apply a new position(when available), and the `setCenter`-method of the map to apply a new center.